# Error in conversion code for minutes to days

Tags: javascript, converters

Found this lovely piece of code on this site and it worked like a charm until it got over 10,000 minutes

```
function minToTime(duration) { /*Call function 2 */
        var minutes = parseInt(duration%60)
            , hours = parseInt((duration/(60))%24)
            , days = parseInt((duration/(60*24))%7);

        days = (days < 10) ? "0" + days : days;
        hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;


        return days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes;
}
```

Can anyone help me find a way to solve this problem? Please bear in mind I am new to javascript and have very basic knowledge.

Thank you in advance

Comment: if your duration in milisec then first dived by 1000. then convert to min

Comment: Thank you to both Anurag and Vivek. Works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to do the `%7` to get the number of days. It might only be beneficial if you further want to aggregate days into weeks. So 13 days would become 1 week and 6 days.

But I don't think you need that, so the following code change should suffice:

```
 var minutes = parseInt(duration%60)
        , hours = parseInt((duration/(60))%24)
        , days = parseInt((duration/(60*24)); //Don't need the %7 here
```

I have put together a [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lw8zzqj/) to explain the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this COnvertmintoday(minutes);

function COnvertmintoday(newMinutes) {

```
minutes_day = 24 * 60
minutes = newMinutes;

days = Math.floor(minutes / minutes_day )

return days 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `%7` lurking around in the calculation of days, which must have been added number of weeks.
Remove that and the code should work fine, or calculate number of weeks too:

```
function minToTime(duration) { /*Call function 2 */
    var minutes = parseInt(duration%60)
        , hours = parseInt((duration/(60))%24)
        , days = parseInt(duration/(60*24));   //remove %7

    days = (days < 10) ? "0" + days : days;
    hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;


    return days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes;
}
```

Alternatively you can use it to get number of weeks:

```
function minToTime(duration) { /*Call function 2 */
  var minutes = parseInt(duration%60)
    , hours = parseInt((duration/(60))%24)
    , days = parseInt(duration/(60*24)%7)
    , weeks = parseInt(duration/(60*24*7));

  days = (days < 10) ? "0" + days : days;
  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  weeks = (weeks < 10) ? "0" + weeks : weeks;


  return weeks + ":" + days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes;
}
```